# Full join two tables on a nonidentical column

Tags: sql, outer-join

Assume T1 is

```
id    val1
1     10
2     20
```

and T2 is

```
id    val2
1     100
3     300
```

I'd like to make

```
id    val1    val2
1     10      100
2     20      null
3     null    300
```

The command that I am using is

```
select T1.id, T1.val1, T2.val2 from T1 full join T2 on T1.id=T2.id
```

It results in

```
id    val1    val2
1     10      100
2     20      null
null  null    300
```

It is missing id=3. What should I use instead of T1.id in the select command to get all the ids and not just those from T1?

Comment: If you get a result from `full join`, you are NOT using MySQL.  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: What database are you using? It seems it's not MySQL.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server. Thanks for pointing out that 'full join' doesn't work in MySQL. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a full join.  You can emulate it with this method:

```
select t1.id, t1.val1, t2.val2
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
union all
select t2.id, null, t2.val2
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null;
```

If your database supports `full join`, you would use either:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, t1.val1, t2.val2
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

or:

```
select id, t1.val1, t2.val2
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what database are you using. MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`, but you seem to be using it. If it's supported, you need to use `COALESCE()` in the key columns. Your query should look like:

```
select coalesce(T1.id, T2.id) as id, T1.val1, T2.val2 
from T1 
full join T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```